# c# Numericupdown to pass a value to an integer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, integer, numericupdown

I'm having a problem passing a numericupdown value into an integer.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = numericUpDown1.Value;
    updateCount(count);
}
```

So, what I want to do is pass the value of the numericupdown value into an integer named count and then pass the value into a method that updates a table in my database.

I just started programming C# lately and can't seem to understand some  documentation.

Comment: What is the error message or issue you face on assigning the value to int

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot of it. I'm really sorry for the question. I know it maybe is simple

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[NumericUpDown.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx) returns decimal so you need to round and convert to integer

Use this,

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(numericUpDown1.Value, 0));
updateCount(count);
```

You can convert directly to the integer type if you have set `Increment` to integer (no decimal points) number, otherwise it is safe to round first before conversion.

So without round

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
updateCount(count);
```

Comment: Yup. You're awesome. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I know this was a while back, but surely `Math.Floor` is better for this than `Math.Round`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the numeric value of the **NumericUpDown** control is **decimal** and you wanted to assign it to a integer type. You should do a **TypeCast** to assign it. For the same there is a **Convert** class you can use it like this

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and post a comment as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, Now I know what the problem is. Lesson learned Sir Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

int count = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: Having like that it will not work, was searching info about this also, since that was my first thougth that did come to my mind and didn't work

Answer (score -1):

This is what it to do:

```
Dim numericUpDown1 As Integer
```